# How to input non-ASCII text to Android device with Appium?

Tags: android, automation, appium, non-ascii-characters, hebrew

I searched Google / Stackoverflow / other forums, tried many ways suggested in those posts but still could not find any working solution.
I need to input non-ASCII text, (Hebrew) using Appium to Android Native application.
Simply `smart.searchField.sendKeys("שלום חבר");`  causes some Gibrish signs to be presented.
Putting the text to clipboard with

```
    String myString = "מה נשמע?";
    StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(myString);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);`
```

and then trying to paste the text with `((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.PASTE));` to the element causes `not implemented` exception.

`((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.LANGUAGE_SWITCH));
((AndroidDriver)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.SWITCH_CHARSET));`

Above code does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [appium-java-client 7.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.1.0) and [Appium Server 1.13.0](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.13.0)

[image]

Make sure that your [`file.encoding` property is set to `UTF-8`](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html) and if you're reading the Hebrew text from external source it stored in UTF-8/Unicode as well.

Also it might be your application issue, i.e. the input doesn't allow non-ASCII characters to be entered, the application lives at http://d242m5chux1g9j.cloudfront.net/eribank.apk, the sample project can be found at https://github.com/seetest-io/java-appium-first-test/. Check out [Appium -> Code Examples -> Java for more details if needed](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. My `defaultCharacterEncoding` is set to `UTF-8` and the application we are testing is definitely using Hebrew inputs, otherwise I would prefer using English input strings.

Comment: Hello Dmitri! After a big pause I'm trying to solve this problem and still did not success.
If possible I'd like to contact you directly.